# Dev express RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit how change column orders/ ubound columns VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

Any one please help
Dev express RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit how to change column orders/ ubound columns after loading datasource from data table at runtime using vb.net
Data Table Columns: Desc,Code,unit,Qty
Change Order Columns: Code,Desc,unit,Qty
Any examples

Comment: Did you search any where here is a link that might help https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit

Comment: yes Sir but there is no any information is available to me regarding my query, Below function working in Dev-Express 9.1, but when I convert into Dev-express 18, they show error in Loop
Please help
Thank you for support.

data table columns: Desc , Code, unit , Qty                                                                                            I want to customize these colums                                                                  
Custom columns: Code , Desc , unit , Qty

Comment: Post some code that is failing I do not work with Dev express So anyone who wants to help will have a better idea of what needs to change to fix your issue